# Should I keep common stop-words when preprocessing for word embedding?

Tags: word-embeddings, word2vec, nlp

If I want to construct a word embedding by predicting a target word given context words, is it better to remove stop words or keep them?

> the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog

or

> quick brown fox jumped lazy dog

As a human, I feel like keeping the stop words makes it easier to understand even though they are superfluous.

So what about for a Neural Network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general stop-words can be omitted since they do not contain any useful information about the content of your sentence or document.

The intuition behind that is that stop-words are the most common words in a language and occur in every document independent of the context. Therefore they contain no valuable information which could hint to the content of the document.

Answer (score 1):

It's not mandatory. Removing stopwords can sometimes help and sometimes not. You should try both.

**A case for not using stopwords**: Using stopwords will provide context to the user's intent. So when you use a contextual model like BERT, all stopwords are kept to provide enough context information like the negation words (not, nor, never) which are considered to be stopwords.

According to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.07531):

> Surprisingly, the stopwords received as much attention as non-stop words, but removing them has no effect in MRR performances.